# WPF Application Data Binding works on initialization, but not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am working on a WPF application and I am trying to have text on the UI update after a button has been pressed. The data binding works for the initialization but when I try to change the text in the code after the button has been pressed, it does not update.

```
    public class UpdateWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _textStatus;
    private readonly DeviceConnection deviceConnection = new DeviceConnection();
    private readonly GetFile getFile = new GetFile();


    public UpdateWindow()
    {
        TextStatus = "This will update the text";
    }

    //The button calls this WriteCommand function
    public void WriteCommand()
    {
        TextStatus="The text on the UI should update here but it doesn't";
        if (getFile.FindFile())
        {
            if (deviceConnection.CheckDeviceConnection())
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                //do something else
            }
        }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


     public string TextStatus { get => _textStatus; set => SetProperty(ref _textStatus, value); }

}
```

And here is my XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="StatusText" Text="{Binding Path=TextStatus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

I'm just not sure why it can initialize but not update.

Comment: As a note, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect on a OneWay Binding like that of the Text property of a TextBlock.

Comment: Besides that, are you sure you call the WriteCommand method on the same view model instance to which the view is bound?

Comment: Good to know I am still new to WPF so thank you for that. You were right it was something as simple as not having the same instance. Got it working now thank you!